# How to print custom message in GraphQL

Tags: mongodb, es6-promise, graphql

Hi I am working with GraphQl with the combination of es6.
While removing a particular record from graphql, I am getting details(values) of the deleted record, I want to print some custom message like "Record deleted". Please help me accordingly.

Here is my graphQL code:

```
removeUser:{
        type: UserType,
        args: {
            _id: {
                description: 'The _id of the user',
                type: GraphQLString,
            },
        },
        resolve: (obj, {_id}) =>{        
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                User.findOne({_id:_id},(err,res)=> {
                    if(err || res == null) {
                        reject('User was not found')
                    } 
                    else {
                        User.remove({_id: _id},(err,result)=>{
                            err ? reject(err) : reject('User removed successfully')
                        });
                    }
                })
            })           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare `UserType` as the type of the `removeUser` field. Obviously, the string `'User removed successfully'` is not a UserType; it's a String type.

Also, if the delete operation is successful, you should call `resolve` in the Promise, not `reject`.

I think something like this should work:

```
removeUser:{
    type: GraphQLString,
    args: {
        _id: {
            description: 'The _id of the user',
            type: GraphQLString,
        },
    },
    resolve: (obj, {_id}) =>{        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            User.findOne({_id:_id},(err,res)=> {
                if(err || res == null) {
                    reject('User was not found')
                } 
                else {
                    User.remove({_id: _id},(err,result)=>{
                        err ? reject(err) : resolve('User removed successfully')
                    });
                }
            })
        })           
    }
}
```